# How to connect PostgreSQL Database to Cypress 10+ , no pg_hba.conf entry error

Tags: javascript, postgresql, cypress

When I try to connect and query on my PostgreSQL database, I keep getting a cypress error:  `“no pg_hba.conf entry for host “ user “postgres”, database “postgres”, SSL off”`. How do I solve the error. Is this an issue with code or with the database?

this is my cypres.config.js file:

```
const pg = require("pg")
module.exports = defineConfig({

  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("task", {
        //create a task - take two parameters - first being a config and second is sql
        READFROMDB({ dbConfig, sql }) {
          //create a client using the config argument
          const client = new pg.Pool(dbConfig)
          //return thw result from sql
          return client.query(sql)

        }
      })
    },

    DB:{
      database: "<name>",
      user: "<name>",
      password: "<pw>",
      host: "<hostname>.amazonaws.com", //not localhost
      port: 5432,
      dialect: "postgres",
      dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
          require: true, // This will help you. But you will see nwe error
          rejectUnauthorized: false // This line will fix new error
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
})
```

This is my test:

```
 cy.task("READFROMDB",{
        //get config from db
        dbConfig: Cypress.config('DB'),

        //SQL we want to perform
        sql: 'select * from user where user=\'Phoebe\''
    }).then((result)=>{
        console.log(result.rows)
    })
```

Comment: Is the host in the error message really reported as the empty string, or did you redact that?

Comment: @jjanes I just edited it :)) it contains my ip address actually

Comment: Based on the intention reflected in your config, it should not attempt to connect without ssl.  But the error message indicates it is attempting to connect without ssl (which attempt the server rejects).  So cypress is not correctly reading you intentions.  I am not a cypress user (and indeed don't recall having heard of it before), so don't know why that might be.  Are you following some tutorial or something?  If so, please link to it.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still running into this error with Cypress, try the following config:

```
db: {
  user: ' ',
  host: ' ',
  database: ' ',
  password: ' ',
  port: '5432',
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
}
```

Credits to: https://catalins.tech/nodejs-postgresql-heroku-error-no-pghbaconf-entry-for-host-ssl-off/